# What do you think about a joint meetup between fitness startups in NYC?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

This is another site promotion idea - but I'm making it a new post because [this one](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/what-do-you-think-about-these-site-promotion-ideas) was getting kind of long.

Anyway, I've been communicating with some health and fitness startups such as [Runkeeper](http://runkeeper.com/home), [Fitocracy](http://www.fitocracy.com/), and [WorkSmart Labs](http://www.worksmartlabs.com/products/). Fitocracy and WorkSmart Labs are both based in NYC near Stack Headquarters. Runkeeper is based in Boston but I know they have plenty of users in the NYC area. What do you think of sponsoring a meetup between all these groups? A representative from each company could give a short talk about what they do, and potentially pick up some new users.

What do you think? How should I structure this to make people want to come? What other groups should I contact?

Also please let me know if you're in the NYC area and would be interested in participating in something like this!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I'm nowhere near the NYC area, but I think it's a great idea to pull groups together. One suggestion I might have for this is try to downplay people selling their product or service, and instead have anyone presenting anything focus on something more educational. Obviously you'll want them to be able to self-promote, but I'm sure I'm not alone in being a little disappointed going to any sort of meetup and having someone try to sell me something instead of teaching me something.

Comment: Good point! What do you mean by focus on something more educational? Like fitness/exercise tips?

Comment: Yeah, tips, routines, nutrition, anything besides "come to our website" and "buy our stuff". Plugs or introductions are fine: "Hi, I'm Joe from X where we offer Y" but make sure it's followed by something people can learn from, and not just "you should buy our product"

Comment: Some kind of physical incentive or goodie bag would be good to entice people to actually go. I stumbled upon a link describing [three strategies to increase webinar attendance](http://www.lewishowes.com/webinars/increase-webinar-attendance/). I like the idea of creating a mystery. That will hook people's curiosity if people think the value is high enough.